# tool for show better code(color code) in html like stackoverflow code sample

Tags: editor

in stackoverflow editor have button call "Code Sample"

which any code write this block in present time show color code

like

```
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

i know this is java script code because when page load, normal text code changed to color text code
but:

what is name of this tool

how can i add this tool to my blog or website

Comment: Don't know about SO, but have a look at [hightlightjs](http://highlightjs.org/).

Comment: this might help https://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: thanks Sirko highlight.js awesome

Comment: thanks Youbaraj Sharma is very good